# How can I use nested objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, nested

I'm trying to write some code, but now i have this problem,
I want to call an object from inside another object like:

```
var obj = new my_obj();

obj.subobj.method1();
obj.subobj.method2();
```

I've tryied something like this:

```
function my_obj() {
    this.subobj = function() {
        this.method1 = function(){}
        this.method2 = function(){}  
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work because there is missing an instance to subobj.

So how can I do?

Comment: `this.subobj = {method1() {}, method2() {}}` would work. You can create objects without using a constructor function.

Comment: If you're not sure how to implement it in the first place, are you sure that's really a useful pattern for you to pursue? Form follows functions and all…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create simple object structure like,

```
obj = {
 subObj:{
  method1 : () => {},
  method1 : () => {}
 }
}
```